# Java Rhino allow access to java from safe Context

Tags: java, sandbox, rhino

I want to create sandbox javascript environment and restrict all acces to java classes but the one I specify. I am trying to achieve this by creating `Context` using `Context.initSafeStandardObjects()`

Is there a way to allow other classes to be used by javascript?
If i create context with `Context.initStandardObjects()`

I can access all java classes which is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You can add an instance of java class into the javascript using:

```
Object wrappedTest = Context.javaToJS(test, scope);
ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "test", wrappedTest); //Where text here is name of the variable
```

Than you can use methods of this class inside javascript, even when u init context using `initSafeStandardObjects`

```
Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, "test.sampleMethod()", "<cmd>",1, null);
System.out.println(cx.toString(result));
```